Unable to get command output in Jenkins console output
I learning Jenkins and I have hit a roadblock. I try executing a freestyle porject with Execute shell as a build step and put something like
echo "Hello world"
The build says successful but it doesn't display Hello world in the console output.
This is the output I get
Started by user Syed Ahmed Haider Razvi

Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\testing
[testing] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins3566058751622145544.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\testing>Finished: SUCCESS


Show the command from the Execute shell step.

I'd recommend to move on and learn Pipelines that store the pipeline workflow as code in a Jenkinsfile. Freestyle projects are history and cannot be used in modern reality.
